# Is CiviCRM SAML 2.0 compatible?

Tags: authentication

I would like to know if CiviCRM conforms to the SAML 2.0 standard for user authentication

Thanks

Norma Tovey

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM itself does not have user authentication. CiviCRM runs within a CMS: Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla or Backdrop. So IMO the question should be: does the CMS you will be using conform to the SAML 2.0 standard?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/samlauth